# Listview multi lines

Tags: vb.net, listview

I created a program to load a text file, should load all lines from the textfile and display them in the listview

However It only loads the first line in the listview how do I get it to read the entire file?

```
Sub Loadbtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Browse.Click
    OpenFD.ShowDialog()
    Dim Path As String = OpenFD.FileName
    Dim AllItems As String
    Try
        AllItems = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path)
        Dim ItemLines As New TextBox
        ItemLines.Text = AllItems
        Dim lv As New ListViewItem
        For Each Line As String In ItemLines.Lines
            List.Items.Add(lv)
            lv.Text = Line
            lv.SubItems.Add(Crypto.AES_Decrypt(Line))
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: you need a NEW lvi for each line to add; and empty Catch is not a good idea, you are just eating any errors that crop up.

Comment: Might sound dumb but im pretty new at this... how do I get it to have an endless loop to where it just adds more lines until all lines have been added? I feel pretty lucky I made it this far honestly.

Comment: I hate to admit it but I am stuck tryin to make this into a loop to add to keep continuing Tried turning this into do while loop or add a vbnewline but I only seem to break the code where it does nothing at all and I really havent any idea how to fix this right now.
Additionally maybe trying to change other formulas of the code that for some reason oddly work that I dont even know why works such as "Textbox" to a OpenFD.path or it would read the contents of the file to display. Honestly I dont even know what my itemlines.text is supposed to even be for I have no textbox I just know it works

Comment: rather than the ReadAllText, if you use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` it will give you a string array with one line per element.  then you dont have to use a UI control to parse it back into lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could look like this:

```
Sub Loadbtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Browse.Click
    OpenFD.ShowDialog()
    ' full path to the file + name
    Dim filename As String = OpenFD.FileName
    Try
        ' check if file exists to prevent errors
        if (File.Exists(filename)) then
            ' fetch complete text into as lines
            Dim Lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename)
            ' iterate over each line
            For Each Line As String In Lines
                Dim lv as new ListViewItem
                ' take it
                lv.Text = Line
                ' and use it
                lv.SubItems.Add(Crypto.AES_Decrypt(Line))
                ' show it
                List.Items.Add(lv)
            Next
        end if
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' inform the user resp. developer
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

As already mentioned use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to read the file line by line and don't suppress errors - inform the user or at least the developer (yourself, using a log file or something appropriate).